# Tooling API - sObject type 'SecurityHealthCheckRisks' is not supported

Tags: tooling-api

q="SELECT RiskType, Setting, SettingGroup, OrgValue, StandardValue FROM SecurityHealthCheckRisks"

[{"message":"sObject type 'SecurityHealthCheckRisks' is not supported.","errorCode":"INVALID_TYPE"}]

The User which I am using has all the needed permissions (View health Check, Manage Health Check, Setup, and Manage Configurations). Moreover, this user is a system admin.

The same code works locally with my developer instance but not on the production instance. I am using a connected App Access token to query the instance.

I verified using the developer console on production and the same query works there.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure you are hitting the URL with the format like below:

https://myinstance.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/tooling/query/?q=+SELECT+SettingRiskCategory,+RiskType,+Setting,+SettingGroup,+OrgValue,+StandardValue+FROM+SecurityHealthCheckRisks

Comment: @santosh , did it not work for you ?